# Don't raise rep requirements to public beta until pro-tem moderators have been empowered

Tags: feature-request, beta-phase

Law.SE just went to public beta and there is exactly one user with enough rep (i.e., over 1000) to review suggested edits.  Now that public users are flooding in a lot more posts need editing, and suggested edits are just jammed in the queue.

Could the private-beta rep limits be maintained for beta sites until pro-tem moderators have been selected so that this problem isn't repeated [over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116779/241697) and [over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132230/241697)?

Comment: Even without pro-tem mods, users can review edits to their own posts and SE staff can review edits.

Comment: Those two avenues are proving inadequate in practice.  SE staff's attention is intermittent and unreliable.  And the users who most need editing seem to be less likely to frequent and accept edits.

Comment: I totally agree with this. Robert Cartaino and animuson have done a good job approving edits on Law, but there's only so much they can do.

Comment: SE staff? On a niche site? Bwahahaha! ;-)

Comment: Or appoint at least one or two of the three pro-tem mods earlier.   You don't have to decide on *all* of them to choose *any* of them.  Health got some of its moderators pretty early because everybody knew the site would need active moderation.